# Docker Server is Unable to Route Network Traffic to Containers?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker server (192.168.56.1/24), however, I can't access any containers with the container's IP address (172.16.0.0/16).

IP forward has been enabled on the Docker Server and I could only reach the docker interface on that server, nothing further.

For example, below is the network interface on Docker:

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.1/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global vboxnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
br-f03a36c56e51: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:7c:73:13:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.1/16 brd 172.16.255.255 scope global br-f03a36c56e51
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:7cff:fe73:136a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

br is the docker interface.

Containers are using 172.16.0.0 network.

On my client is on the same network (192.168.56.0/24), and could ping 172.16.0.1. However, the client couldn't ping containers, for instance: 172.16.0.2.

But, if I went into the container, I could successfully ping my client.

No firewall is configured on the container.

Comment: You can't reach the Docker-internal IP addresses from other hosts.  It's one of the good reasons to never look up these implementation details at all.  Use the `docker run -p` option to make your container visible via a port on the host.

Comment: Yeah, I know port mapping, but I don't want that. I have several web and mail running on docker for testing, I don't want to use irregular ports which hard to remember